# How can I transfer resolution time data from JIRA to Confluence for metric analysis?

Tags: jira, confluence, agile, jira-plugin, jira-agile

How can I transfer resolution time data from JIRA to Confluence for metric analysis?
I am able to access JIRA from Confluence and able to see other fields like Status., but I need Resolution time - (created date - resolved date)

Answer (score 0):

If you need time of resolution (time when issue was resolved), simply add Resolved (or resolutionDate) as another field to your Jira Issue macro in Confluence.

If you mean resolution time (i.e. resolutionDate - creationDate), then you have to first prepare this field to Jira and then you can display it in Confluence. If you already have such information (since you mention "transfer to Confluence"), then just add it as a field to your Jira Issue macro in Confluence.

If you don't have such field, you will need prepare such information using some scripting (ScriptRunner's script fields or any other add-on - explore [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/) for possibilities).

You also didn't mention if you run on-prem Jira (Server/DC) or Jira Cloud.